# HTML5 Canvas stroke width doesn't change incrementaly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to incrementally change my line width.
But the following code doesn't work:

```
var csMargin = 10; //Color select margin
var csSize   = 15;
var csNumber = 4;

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = (csMargin * 2 + csSize) * csNumber;
canvas.height = (csMargin * 2 + csSize) * csNumber;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

function DrawCS(){
    for(i = 0; i < csNumber; i++){
        for(j=0; j< csNumber ;j++){
            ctx.rect(csMargin*(i+1)+i*csSize,csMargin*(j+1)+j*csSize,csSize,csSize)

            //the line width should increase as j increases!!
            ctx.lineWidth=j*2;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}

DrawCS();
```

I should be getting a line width that gets thicker every line but I get the same thickness from every square.

[image: Wrong result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `ctx.beginPath();` before your `ctx.rect(...).`

Then to avoid that zero width use e.g.:

```
ctx.lineWidth=(j+1)*2;
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 
<script>
  var csMargin = 10; //Color select margin
  var csSize   = 15;
  var csNumber = 4;

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = (csMargin * 2 + csSize) * csNumber;
  canvas.height = (csMargin * 2 + csSize) * csNumber;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  function DrawCS(){
    ctx.stroke();
    for(i = 0; i < csNumber; i++){
      for(j=0; j< csNumber ;j++){
        ctx.beginPath();     
        ctx.rect(csMargin*(i+1)+i*csSize,csMargin*(j+1)+j*csSize,csSize,csSize);
        ctx.lineWidth=(j+1)*2;
        //the line width should increase as j increases!!     
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }

  DrawCS();
</script>
```